Prettier formatting differs in VSCode and Neovim
This happens mostly due to ternary operators in javascript/typescript files. It looks something like this in Neovim:
intent={
    invoiceNumberError === ""
        ? Intent.NONE
        : existingVoteNumbers.length > 0
            ? Intent.DANGER
            : Intent.NONE
}

And in my VSCode, it looks something like:
intent={
    invoiceNumberError === ""
        ? Intent.NONE
        : existingVoteNumbers.length > 0
        ? Intent.DANGER
        : Intent.NONE
}

The ternary operator is formatted differently in terms of spacing. I'm just not sure what to do with this. I have a .prettierrc:
{
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "semi": true,
  "singleQuote": false,
  "printWidth": 80
}

This causes a change in the codebase and it will be included in the git diff. I want to prevent this since my team consists of neovim and vscode users, and we don't want these redundant code changes.

Turns out that this happens because my neovim's mason is using the latest version of prettier which is at 3.2.5, but VSCode's prettier is using 2.x versioning (which I gather from the github repo CHANGELOG). This causes some indentation difference between the two versions. So what I did was I just ran
:MasonInstall prettier@2.8.8 // Note: `2.8.8` is the latest version of `2.x

and they are now in sync.

It's also important to note that if you update all Mason packages with bulk update, the prettier will also be updated. So, if you were using the previous version, you'll need to reinstall it after the bulk update.
